# is this question asked before what do banks benefits from credit points programs

Tags: discussion

I want to know if this question was asked before offcourse I ill elaborate with details

what do banks benefits from credit points programs ? why banks encourage clients to use credit card and win them gifts related to points ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some examples:

[How can banks afford to offer credit card rewards?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/17061/how-can-banks-afford-to-offer-credit-card-rewards)

[How can credit card companies offer a cash back program?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/59123/how-can-credit-card-companies-offer-a-cash-back-program)

[Why are earning credit card rewards often tied to groceries and gas?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48981/why-are-earning-credit-card-rewards-often-tied-to-groceries-and-gas)

The questions were found by combining these two tags: [credit-card](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-card) [reward-program](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reward-program)

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-card+reward-program